# Problems with Indices of Magento.

Tags: magento-1.6

I made an indexing Indices at my store, and yet they are still with the status "processing". 
Even I have the reindexed via ssh, the status is still "processing".
And due to this, new registered products are not being displayed in my store.

Have googled but have not found solution for this, someone has been there, someone with some advice on how to solve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by deleting the files from **var/locks** folder